# Reversing facts in prolog and display them

Tags: prolog, fact

If I have the following:

```
friends(tim,joe).
```

if i go:

```
?- friends(X,Y).
```

I would get:

```
X=tim
Y=joe
```

What would I have to print the following with out adding any new facts

```
X=tim
Y=joe
X=joe
Y=tim
```

Comment: do you want all four lines printed out all at once?

Comment: if it is possible, yes

Comment: this is not possible in Prolog. If `X=joe`, it can't be also `X=tim`, because `tom=joe` is impossible. `tim` is not `joe`. But, you can have `[s(tim,joe), s(joe,tim)]` printed as a solution to a predicate ("s" for "solution").

Comment: actually, everything is possible in Prolog as Prolog is Turing complete, so it is possible to make a predicate that will _print_ the four lines as you requested; but it will not produce them as a solution, because the solution that has `X=tim` and at the same time `X=joe` is self-contradictory.

Comment: by any chance would you know how to go about it

Comment: this is really an ill-advised adventure, but OK, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add a new *rule*:

```
are_friends(X,Y):- friends(X,Y).
are_friends(X,Y):- friends(Y,X).
```

Then you ask:

```
?- are_friends(X,Y).
```

Prolog will answer

```
X=tim, Y=joe   _
```

and it will wait for your further command. If you press `;`, then it will print the next solution:

```
X=tim, Y=joe   ;

X=joe, Y=tim   _
```

---

To just *show* the results twice - as opposed to *producing* them in a proper Prolog fashion - we can write

```
show_friends :- 
  friends(X,Y),
  write('X='), write(...), write(', Y='), write(...), nl,
  write('X='), write(...), write(', Y='), write(...), nl,
  fail.
```

but this is really, *really*, ***really*** just ***faking it***. Ughgh. You fill in the blanks.

Comment: is it possible to do this if i ask friend(X,Y) for it to print both of the solutions without using are_friends

Comment: @spikestar no. if you call `friends(X,Y)`, and the only fact there is, is `friends(tim,joe)`, then this is what you will get. Does this answer your question?